# Open ERP 7 - What function is called to update a record. Need to inherit this

Tags: python, openerp-7

It was said that in OpenERP the functions def create(self, cr, user, vals, context=None) and def update(self, cr, user, vals, context=None) exist within the orm.Model that are called if you save a new record or if you update one.
I need to inherit those functions to prevent ERP from saving or updating any records if certain typed-in data have the wrong format.
I found the create function and was able to inherit and my implementation for this what I wanted works fine with that. However, I wasn't able to find the function that is called when I want to update a record. It is definitely not "update" 
I'm using OpenERP 7. What function is called for updating a record?
Please can anybody help

That's what I tried now, but it is not called:

```
def write(self, cr, user, ids, vals, context=None):
    tasks2 = vals['task_ids']
    obj_task = self.pool.get('project.task')
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    valid = False
    if not tasks:
        valid = False
    else:
        for t in tasks:
            task_vals = t[2]
            if not task_vals['date_deadline'] and vals['type'] == 'lead':
                raise osv.except_osv(_('Error!'),_('You cannot have a task without a valid date.'))
            elif datetime.datetime.strptime(task_vals['date_deadline'], '%Y-%m-%d') >= date:
                valid = True
    if not valid and vals['type'] == 'lead':
        raise osv.except_osv(_('Error!'),_('You cannot create/edit a lead without any non-expired action.'))
    else:
        valid = True
    if valid:
        return super(crm_lead_inherit, self).write(self, cr,uid,vals,context=context)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is called Write.

i give you an easy example:

```
def write(self, cr, uid, ids, values, context=None):

    values['a_field'] = 'Hello';

    rs = super(Class, self).write(cr, uid, ids, values, context=context)

    return rs
```

Values is the dict that you should edit and return edited since it containts the values that are updating, with that, every time you run the write function you will put hello to the field called 'a_field'

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for your answer. I tested to inherit this function on Friday, but it has never been called. As I need the same functionality for creating as well as updating a record I know that the file in which I inherited the function is definitely correct because the inherited create function is called when I create a new record. When I edit this record, the inherited write function (the second function) is never called. What is the difference between the inheritance of the create function and the write function? Why is the write function not called?

Comment: In v7 isnt any difference, you should check if another module inherits and overwrites it and maybe thats why yours isnt running. Try to do a grep or something to check that, it may be a bad overwriting.

Comment: This would explain why my function isn't called. On the whole server I found the write-function 99 times (none of them were written by myself). Is there any way to find out which of this functions might affect my one? I don't know what "grep" is. And how can I avoid this affect without changing any other modules. I only want to make changes in my own module as it should be.

Comment: grep is a unix command to search for plain-text, thing is that, of that 99 times that you found it you should check which one is of that model, the only way you can do that if other module did a bad overwriting is to do a dependence of that module too, else, you should touch this module. Do this, inside odoo, go to Configuration > Database structure > Models, search for your model, there, you will see what modules touch that object. Search what of these modules touch the write function and you can try to put logs there